# dplyr - %in% always returning false when used against a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use mutate function in dplyr to createa string feature. Basically, if a given value is present in another dataframe, I want to retain the value. Otherwise, I wat to replace it with unknown. When I try the following code, all values always come out as "unknown" regardless of whether they are present in the dataframe I am using to lookup.
what am i doing wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataframe_name['column_name']` returns a dataframe. You need a vector in `ifelse` which can be achieved with either `[[` or `$` so you should use `dataframe_name[['column_name']]` or `dataframe_name$column_name`.

For example using `mtcars` dataset as an example see the difference in the outputs.

```
mtcars['cyl'] %in% 6
#[1] FALSE

mtcars[['cyl']] %in% 6
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

mtcars$cyl %in% 6
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

This might be a useful read - [The difference between bracket [ ] and double bracket [[ ]] for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el)